# undefined index on a session variable even though I have set a cookie

Tags: php

I am trying to set cookies to a php session variable so that a session does not expire for 2 months. The problem I am getting though is that after about 3 hours, when I refresh the page, I get a undefined index for `$_SESSION['id']` in line 30. But I don't get the undefined index for `$_SESSION['id']` in between lines 20-23.

Why am I still getting undefined indexes even though I have set cookies for this session variable?

```
$inTwoMonths = 60 * 60 * 24 * 60 + time();
    setcookie('id', 'ID', $inTwoMonths);


    //line 20-23
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

    }

    //line 30
    <?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>
```

Comment: Is that after three hours of inactivity, or are you using the site for those hours and they just disappear?

Comment: @andrewsi it is hours of inactivity

Comment: See MrSil's answer - your webserver is expiring your sessions. You need to tell it to extend their lifespan. The reason you're not getting an error for line 22 is because that's not triggered - that code's only run if `$_POST['id']` is set, which I assume is only done when someone's logging in.

Comment: @andrewsi so it setcookie() worthless then if I need to set SESSION TTL a lot longer?

Comment: You're setting two things - a cookie and a session. But you're only checking the $_SESSION variable. You can either set your own cookies, which are a lot easier to give a long expiry date to; or use sessions, where you need to tweak the server settings to make them last longer, but which I find a lot easier to work with - everything is in $_SESSION and the server takes care of the details for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SESSION != COOKIE.

You must set SESSION TTL in php.ini (20min default).

On line 20-23 you dont get undefined index, coz you setting var. But on line 30 you trying to read undefined variable(coz you dont set-up it before.)

Try something like this:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
```

Also you need use session_start(); to init session.

Comment: The problem is that if I do this then when I do an echo, the echo isn't correct as instead of echoing "COT" for example, it echos "ID". This is when I tried to set `$_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];` and `echo $_SESSION['id']`. If I try echo `$_COOKIE['id']` then it outputs a bunch of numbers such as '0245232232'